# Zune HD development limitations

Tags: zune, zune-hd

I'm wondering if I can write something like reading app (to turn my Zune HD into the Amazon Reader)

Can I write applications?

How am I limited with API? Can I use network and FS? Can I embed a browser to the app? Can I use XML parser, XSL, etc? Are something like Windows Forms there?

How am I limited with development, do I need to do some terrible things which are needed to develop for iPod?

Comment: No amount of software will turn the Zune into the Kindle. It's all about the hardware.

Comment: It was something like stupid joke :)

Comment: Everything I managed to found is not about HD but previous versions of Zune :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own experience:

Can I write applications? Yes.

Can I use network and FS? Nope.

Can I embed a browser to the app? No.

Can I use XML parser, XSL, etc? Yeah.

Are something like Windows Forms there? No. (I had to implement a basic toolkit by hand, pretty interesting experience)

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of **OpenZDK**?

> "That’s about to change. Through the work of myself as well as Netrix, Nurta, and the rest of the ZuneBoards Development Front, all Zune models, including the Zune HD, have been hacked. The first true hack available for the Zune, this makes it possible to, for the first time, run applications directly on top of the Zune firmware, with full access to everything XNA withheld before. The limitations of XNA are now no limitations at all."  (from Zune Boards: http://www.zuneboards.com/?p=vB50442)

The OpenZDK wiki: http://zunedevwiki.org/wiki/